# Zend_Search_Lucene range query error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I have set up each document with a date field. (keyword)

Values stored in it are in this format; 20100511

Each time I try to perform a ranged query, I get the following error:

```
date:[10000000 TO 20000000]
```

> At least one range query boundary term
>   must be non-empty term

Anyone got a clue?

**Update**

I have gotten this to work programmatically. 
Does that mean the parser is buggy?

```
$from  = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('10000000', 'dateOfBirthMod');
$to    = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('20000000', 'dateOfBirthMod');
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Range($from, $to, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [it is a bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5227) in the query parser (quite old btw). I would suggest that you either add a comment to that issue or open a new one to confirm that it is still happening in version x.x of the ZF.

Comment: Wow, that bug was reported more than a year ago. I'll comment on it just to be sure.

Thanks for your help nuqqsa.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is more of a questionable default, not a bug.  You can change the analyzer to allow numbers.  In fact, you can even write a custom analyzer. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.extending.html

The setting for allowing numbers to be tokenized is

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive());
```

in Zf 1.x and in Zf 2.x

```
Zend\Search\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend\Search\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\TextNum\CaseInsensitive());
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a workaround for this bug which stems from the method called tokenize() which does not return any value and which may be found in the Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer.php

You can try to replace the code with the following one if you use the latest ZF release (1.10.7).

```
public function tokenize($data, $encoding = '')
{
    $this->setInput($data, $encoding);

    $tokenList = array();
    /*
    while (($nextToken = $this->nextToken()) !== null) {
        $tokenList[] = $this->_input;
    }
    */
        $tokenList[] = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Token( $this->_input, 1, 1 );

    return $tokenList;
}
```

I don't know whether it works in older releases or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change default Analyzer to TextNum to allow number before finding

ZF2:

```
\ZendSearch\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Analyzer::setDefault(new \ZendSearch\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\TextNum\CaseInsensitive());
```

Second, your date field MUST be a keyword, not text.